Amazon athena, presto sql :INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot unnest type: varchar
Have some transaction data and the data looks like:
record_id     labels
001           ['first_record','transfer']
002           ['withdraw', 'holiday']
003           ['direct','change_password','transfer']
004           ['change_password']
......

Labels column is of string type.
Tried to unnest labels column
select record_id, new_labels  from  transactions, UNNEST(labels ) as t(new_labels )   order by record_id, new_labels

but got following error

INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Cannot unnest type: varchar

Then tried to cast string to array then to the unnest
select record_id, cast(json_parse(labels)  as array(varchar)) as labels from transactions 

but got following error:

INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast to array(varchar). ['withdraw', 'holiday']

Then simply tried
select cast(['first_record','transfer']) as array(varchar)

it returned

mismatched input '['. Expecting: 



select cast(['first_record','transfer']) as array(varchar)

Here you got the syntax wrong, it should be:
select cast(array['first_record','transfer'] as array(varchar));

And cast here is actually redundant.

INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast to array(varchar). ['withdraw', 'holiday']

You need to check the exact data you have, parsing and casting correctly formatted json string works just fine:
select cast(json_parse('["first_record","transfer"]') as array(varchar));

Output:
          _col0           
--------------------------
 [first_record, transfer] 

One of the potential issues here is double encoding - for example see Regular expression to stop at first match of one or the other character
